# Retornar o tamanho do "período" de uma cadeia de bits

Tags: algoritmo

Recentemente fiz um teste online bastante interessante (da [Codility](https://codility.com/)). Infelizmente esse teste era cronometrado (30 minutos) e acabei não conseguindo chegar a uma solução satisfatória para uma das perguntas.

## Contexto

Um número decimal pode ser visto como uma sequência de bits.

**Exemplos:**

```
955 = 1110111011
10 =  1010
627 = 1001110011
102 = 1100110
104 = 1101000
```

Essas strings de bits podem ser periódicas, ou seja, compostas por sucessivas repetições de substrings de bits.

**Update**

Da definição oficial do problema. Dada uma String `S` composta por `Q` bits. O período `P` é o menor inteiro positivo tal que:

- **P ≤ Q / 2** e
- **S[K] = S[K+P]** para todo **K**, onde **0 ≤ K < Q − P**.

**Exemplos**:

O binário **1010** é composto da substring **10** repetida duas vezes. O binário **1110111011** é composto pela substring **1110** repetida duas vezes e meia (pois o *11* sobra no final após duas repetições). Já o decimal **1101000** não é periódico (não existe uma substring  com `Q / 2` que forme um período).

O período de uma string binária nada mais é do que o tamanho da sequência de bits que se repete.

```
955-> 1110 (período 4)
10 ->  10  (período 2)
627 -> 10011 (período 5)
102 -> 1100 (4, mas esse não é um período válido pois `P > Q / 2`)
104 -> não tem
```

## O problema

Dado um inteiro `n`, escrever um algoritmo que retorne o período da string binária de `n` ou `-1` caso a string binária não seja periódica:

```
public int periodo(int n)
```

## Complexidade esperada

- Pior caso temporal **O(log(N)²)**
- Pior caso espacial **O(log(N))**

## Uma possível solução subótima de força bruta

Eu perdi muito tempo nessa pergunta e nem sei se consegui chegar a uma solução *naive* correta (meu *feeling* era que essa era uma pergunta de manipulação de bits, no fim acabei usando `Integer.toBinaryString(n)` e indo pela força bruta).

Acabei fazendo o seguinte:

- Gerar cada substring candidata a ser um período de `n`. Começando de 1 até [tamanho da string de bits de n] / 2

  ```
   final String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
   for (int i = 1; i < binaryString.length() / 2; i++) {
       final String period = binaryString.substring(0, i);
  ```
- Para cada uma dessas *substrings*, verificar se a string principal poderia ser gerada a partir de repetições da substring (usando um loop e comparando caractere a caractere):

  ```
  private boolean checkSolution(String binaryString, String period) {
      boolean isPeriod = true;
      for (int i = 0; isPeriod && i < binaryString.length(); i++) {
          if (binaryString.charAt(i) != period.charAt(i % period.length())) {
              isPeriod = false;
          }
      }

      return isPeriod;
  }
  ```
- Retornar o menor período encontrado (ou -1 que é o *default* se nenhum período foi encontrado).

Porém não fiquei satisfeito com essa solução... Principalmente por que ela é basicamente quadrática em relação a `Q`, passando bem longe da complexidade temporal esperada.

Minha pergunta é, alguém já resolveu esse problema e conhece um algoritmo melhor? Não precisa ser em Java, um pseudo-código ou implementação em qualquer linguagem está ok.

Comment: I call shenaningans! 110100 é a sequência 110100 repetida exatamente uma vez!

Comment: Esse problema me é vagamente familiar... Tenho certeza que existe uma solução envolvendo autômato finito, e é bem semelhante ao problema de casar uma string com uma expressão regular. Vou tentar me recordar melhor, mas já fica a dica.

Comment: É, também pensei em Fecho de Kleene, mas não consegui pensar em nenhum algoritmo para inferir o alfabeto dada a palavra, ainda mais por permitir casos de composição parcial como a do `905 = 1110111011`. Mais tarde também esbarrei nos algoritmos de [detecção de ciclos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection) mas não consegui formular o problema exatamente conforme a proposta dos algoritmos.

Comment: Desconsidere o que eu disse sobre autômatos, pensei neles pois estive recentemente relendo [isto](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html). Mas o problema que eu me recordava era outro (*string search*), não tem nada a ver com padrões repetidos não... Quanto à sua proposta de solução, creio que não está longe da solução ótima não, embora *talvez* dê pra reduzir um pouco o espaço de soluções (estou com umas ideias aqui, mas como sou *péssimo* em matemática não sei é coisa da minha cabeça ou não... se tiver algo concreto, depois volto aqui).

Comment: P.S. Concordo que as repetições têm de ser inteiras, senão abre muita margem pra "gambiarra"... Ex.: `101110010` é `1011100` repetido 1 vez e 2/7.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Mas uma coisa tem de ficar bem clara, no primeiro caso, existem 2.5 períodos de 4? E que assim haveria uma infinidade de períodos e parece-me que fosse de muito difícil resolução. Ate poderias ter um decimal com vários períodos. 
Agora se for só períodos exatos ai já se consegue fazer.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Embora de fato eu não tenha uma resposta (desisti!), deixo aqui uma pergunta adicional - pra te ajudar a clarear as ideias: você quer o **maior** padrão que se repete, ou o **menor**? Porque se sua cadeia for `0000000...` então há um padrão de tamanho 1, um de tamanho 2, um de tamanho 3... E embora eu não consiga provar, suspeito fortemente que se existem dois padrões com tamanhos `A` e `B` então também existe um com tamanho `mdc(A,B)` - mesmo se eles forem primos entre si (vai ter um padrão de tamanho `1`). Ou seja, quando achar o menor, pare - pois todos serão múltiplos dele.

Comment: @Jorge B. por 2.5 períodos eu não quero dizer realmente uma fração, e sim que pode haver um "resto" incompleto da string binária (Veja o exemplo do 905 = 1110 1110 11), ou seja, a última repetição pode ser parcial e não completa (esse caso estava previsto no exercício).

Comment: @mgibsonbr acho que encontrei uma solução http://stackoverflow.com/a/21171365/664577. (Página 340 desse PDF aqui http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~mac/REC/text-algorithms.pdf), deixe eu tentar relembrar um pouco de Pascal, assim que eu conseguir entender a solução posto uma resposta hehehe.

Comment: Pessoal, recebi hoje os "resultados" do exame, que mostrava a definição do problema, bem como os piores casos esperados. Infelizmente a solução que encontrei acima também não é ótima, logo, o problema continua em aberto. Dei uma limpada nos comentários e inclui definições oficiais. @utluiz, vide as definições o exercício está procurando o menor padrão mesmo (bom *feeling*).

Comment: @JorgeB., também vide as definições oficiais, realmente padrões parciais são aceitáveis, desde que `P < Q / 2`, ou seja, que o padrão se repita ao menos duas vezes.

Comment: Essa complexidade esperada está expressa em função de que? Lembre-se que, para um inteiro `n`, o tamanho de sua cadeia de bits é [o teto de] `log2(n)`. Ou seja, uma solução "quadrática em relação a Q" corresponde exatamente a `log2(n)^2`...

Comment: Humm... Faz sentido @mgibsonbr. Nos meus resultados eu estourei o tempo limite de alguns testes unitários (mas meu algoritmo tinha um problema besta... Só consegui 38 dos 100 pontos). Talvez você tenha razão e eu esteja querendo otimizar uma solução já "suficientemente boa".

Comment: [Este paper aqui](http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~rytter/MYPAPERS/Crochemore-Ilie-Rytter.pdf) parece ser um bom caminho...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A princípio considerei aplicar o algoritmo de [detecção de ciclos de Floyd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection), também conhecido como o algoritmo da "tartaruga e do coelho", mas o problema parece ser mais simples do que isso.

Características de complexidade logarítmicas geralmente envolvem uma comparação que vai diminuindo ao longo do tempo. Por exemplo, a busca binária, que vai dividindo o vetor sempre em dois.

O fato dela ser elevada ao quadrado também poderia estar associado a comparações entre os elementos do vetor, como ocorre com o algoritmo de ordenação bolha (*bubble sort*).

Considerando tudo isso, mais a definição do problema:

> **S[K] = S[K+P]** para todo **K**, onde **0 ≤ K < Q − P**

Pensei num algoritmo simples que funciona basicamente da seguinte forma:

> 1. Calcula o maior período dividindo o tamanho da cadeia de bits por 2, fazendo `P = T / 2`, sendo `T` o tamanho da cadeia de bits.
> 2. Calcula a quantidade de cadeias a comparar fazendo `Q = LEN / P`, arredondando-se sempre para cima
> 3. Para cada `K = 1..P` e `J = 2..K`, compara cada elemento na posição `K` com o correspondente na posição `K * J + P`, somente quando `K * J + P <= T`
>
>    Se encontrar um elemento diferente
>
>    - Se `P > 1`, decrementa o período `P` e retorna ao passo `2` novamente
>    - Senão, continua no passo `4`
> 4. Se `P <= 0` retorna `-1`, senão, retorna `P`

## Exemplo prático

Dado o número de exemplo `955`, cujo valor binário é `1110111011`, podemos calcular os valores inicias dos Passos 1 e 2 da seguinte forma:

```
T = 10
P = 10 / 2 = 5
Q = 10 / 5 = 2
```

Então a comparação no Passo 3 ocorre da seguinte forma:

> `K = 1`: **1** 1 1 0 1 | **1** 1 0 1 1 (iguais)
>
> `K = 2`: 1 **1** 1 0 1 | 1 **1** 0 1 1 (iguais)
>
> `K = 3`: 1 1 **1** 0 1 | 1 1 **0** 1 1 (diferentes)

Ao comparar o terceiro elemento de cada período, um elemento diferente foi encontrado. Então, atualizados as variáveis assim:

```
P = P - 1 = 4
Q = 10 / 3 = 4 (arredondando para cima)
```

E continuamos a comparação:

> `K = 1`: **1** 1 1 0 | **1** 1 1 0 | **1** 1 (iguais)
>
> `K = 2`: 1 **1** 1 0 | 1 **1** 1 0 | 1 **1** (igualis)
>
> `K = 3`: 1 1 **1** 0 | 1 1 **1** 0 | 1 1 (iguais)
>
> `K = 4`: 1 1 1 **0** | 1 1 1 **0** | 1 1 (iguals)

Como não há diferença, então retornamos o valor de `P`, que é `4`.

## Implementação em Java

```java
public static int periodo( int n ) {

  // validação inicial: precisa ser positivo e com pelo menos duas casas binárias
  if( n < 2 ) return -1;

  // inicialização de variáveis
  String s = Integer.toBinaryString( n );
  byte[ ] bytes = s.getBytes();
  int t = bytes.length;

  // período inicial
  int p = t / 2;

  // verifica se o período se repete pelo menos uma vez
  boolean diferente;
  do {
    diferente = false;
    int qp = t / p; // quantidade de períodos
    if (t % p > 0) qp++; //somar 1 para comparar os caracteres de resto no final

    // verifica se a repetição ocorre
    for2: for( int k = 0 ; k < p ; k++ ) {
      for (int j = 1; j < qp; j++) {
        if( k + p * j < t && bytes[ k ] != bytes[ k + p * j ] ) {
          diferente = true;
          break for2;
        }
      }
    }

    //se não encontrou repetição, tenta um período menor
    if( diferente ) {
      p--;
    }
  } while( diferente && p > 0 );

  return p <= 0 ? -1 : p;
}
```

## Algumas Considerações

Não sou muito bom em julgar a complexidade de um algoritmo, mas acredito que no pior caso o algoritmo acima irá fazer `N / 2` iterações e, em cada uma, ele faz iterações em períodos menores, o que leva a uma complexidade logarítmica temporal.

Quanto à complexidade especial (de memória), o algoritmo é `O(1)` porque não acrescenta novas estruturas de dados além da original, embora a implementação seja `O(N)` porque cria um vetor auxiliar do mesmo tamanho da cadeia de bits.

Algo que me deixa com uma pulga atrás da orelha é que o problema sugeriu uma complexidade especial também logarítmica, então talvez haja alguma estrutura de dados que possa otimizar a complexidade temporal da solução.

Uma solução que pensei com complexidade temporal logarítmica é dividir a cadeia de bits em várias Strings e então comparar para ver se elas possuem o mesmo conteúdo. Porém, suspeito que essa solução seria bem menos eficiente, já que executar vários `substring`s me parece algo desnecessário, além do que a comparação de Strings também ocorreria caractere a caractere.

Outra ideia é recuperar o trecho binário de cada período e comparar o equivalente em seu formato numérico. Talvez ainda com operações binárias o algoritmo pudesse ser muito eficiente. Mas não analisei a complexidade da conversão de cada período do formato binário para o decimal.

Ainda outra ideia para otimizar isso ainda mais seria fazer toda essa comparação usando operadores binários para verificar a igualdade dos períodos, por exemplo, usando cadeias de bits assim: `1000010000`, `1000100010`, `1001001001`, `1010101010`. É uma ideia.

Enfim, não sei se a solução que propus atende ao requisito da pergunta, mas espero ter ajudado pelo menos com algumas ideias.

E, antes de concluir, só um alerta: cuidado com o desempenho da linguagem ao participar de um desafio online. Já resolvi alguns desses problemas usando Java e Python. Infelizmente, muitas vezes obtive um *timeout* mesmo com um bom algoritmo. Alguns sites adicionam multiplicadores de velocidade, por exemplo, Java `1,5` e Python `2,5` para tentar igualar a eficiência do algoritmo com linguagens mais velozes como C++. Porém, isso nem sempre é justo e basta olhar o *ranking* para ver quais linguagens estão sempre no topo.

---

## Atualização

Baseado no [gist](https://gist.github.com/aaccioly/fc89c6d2ab862f7a629b) do Anthony Accioly, fiz uma tentativa de otimizar ainda mais o código usando somente manipulação em bits. Segue o código:

```
public class BitPeriod5 {

    public int solution(int n) {

        // validação inicial: precisa ser positivo e com pelo menos duas casas binárias
        if (n < 2) {
            return -1;
        }

        // inicialização de variáveis
        final int t = 32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(n);

        // descarta bits não significantes
        final int s = n >>> Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(n);

        // período inicial
        int p = 1;
        int maxp = t / 2;
        int vp = 0;

        // verifica se o período se repete pelo menos uma vez
        boolean diferente;
        do {
            diferente = false;
            int qp = t / p + 1;
            if (t != p * qp) {
                qp++; //somar 1 para comparar os caracteres de resto no final
            }

            vp = vp << 1 | 1;
            int vi = n & vp;
            for (int i = 1; i < qp; i++) {
                if (((n >> (i*p)) & vp) != (vi & vp)) {
                    diferente = true;
                }
            }

             //se não encontrou repetição, tenta um período menor
            if (diferente) {
                p++;
            }
        } while (diferente && p <= maxp);

        return p > maxp ? -1 : p;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final BitPeriod5 bitPeriod = new BitPeriod5();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            long nano = System.nanoTime();
            for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {
                bitPeriod.solution(10);
                bitPeriod.solution(187);
                bitPeriod.solution(955);
                bitPeriod.solution(1000000000);
                bitPeriod.solution(0b10101000001010100000);
            }
            System.out.printf("%.2f\n", ((double) (System.nanoTime()) - nano) * 1e-6);
        }
    }

}
```

Entretanto, notei que essa solução acaba sendo mais lenta que a que a anterior, mesmo tendo um `for` a menos.

> **Lição 1**
>
> Manipular bits é mais "caro" que acessar elementos do vetor e comparar o seu valor.

Também notei que retirando a operação de módulo, o desempenho do código melhora bastante.

Alterando o trecho:

```
if (t % qp > 0) ...
```

Por isso:

```
if (t != p * qp) ...
```

O ganho de desempenho foi na faixa dos 25%. É muito interessante ver como cada operação a mais afeta drasticamente o desempenho.

> **Lição 2**
>
> A operação de módulo da divisão é muito "cara" do ponto de vista de desempenho.

Comment: Obrigado utluiz, a sua solução executa bem mais rápido do que a minha (mesmo que a complexidade assintótica pareça ser igual). Quanto a complexidade de espaço **log(N)**, vou pela teoria do mgibsonbr, acredito que **log(N) =~ Q**, ou seja que você pode usar uma estrutura qualquer extra para conter os bits da cadeia. Não sei porque, mas ainda tenho a impressão que com um `BitSet` ou mesmo manipulações / operações lógicas de bits seria possível resolver esse problema de maneira mais eficiente. Talvez parte dos passos possam ser reescritos com shits binários e operação `XOR` / `AND NOT`.

Comment: E obrigado pela dica do *timeout* também, gostaria de poder executar esse teste de novo :).

Comment: Criei [um gist](https://gist.github.com/aaccioly/fc89c6d2ab862f7a629b) com seu algoritmo ligeiramente modificado (começando com `p=1` e indo até `p == t / 2`, de forma a retornar sempre o menor período possível). Conforme meu *flawed microbenchmark* sua solução consegue rodar 500.000 testes em torno de 3 vezes mais rápido que a minha. Ainda vou perseguir a questão de bits, mas para todos os fins a sua resposta está correta.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Muito bom. Eu não havia me atentado ao requisito de ser o "menor inteiro positivo". :)

Comment: utluiz, para fechar o assunto de vez, atualizei o Gist acima com uma versão de força bruta e uma versão do seu algoritmo usando apenas manipulação de bits :). Também acho que na linha `if (t % q > 0) qp++;` você provavelmente quis dizer `if (t % **qp** > 0) qp++;` né?

Comment: Bom, resumo da opera. **BitPeriod4.java** = Variação da sua implementação apenas com manipulação de bits, **BitPeriod3.java** = Implementação **naive** com bits. Em termos de *performance*: Sua implementação melhora muito apenas com bits (consome metade do tempo da versão original), mas por algum motivo meu algoritmo descrito abaixo (versão *naive* que vai concatenando períodos) foi a que se saiu melhor. A versão final ficou aproximadamente 6 vezes mais rápida que a original conforme o **microbenchmark** :D. E dito isso, não quero mais escovar bits por um tempo hehehe.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Era `if (t % q > 0) qp++;` mesmo. A divisão anterior irá truncar se houver um resto. Isso significaria que se o último período tiver menos dígitos do que o tamanho do período, o mesmo não será verificado. Então, se houver resto daquela divisão, soma-se um. Daria no mesmo fazer uma divisão arredondando sempre pra cima, mas acabei fazendo desse jeito para não usar classes de arredondamento adicionais. Pelo menos é o meu entendimento.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Acabei de descobrir o quanto a operação de módulo e a manipulação de bits em java pode ser cara. Tentei de forma frustrada fazer uma otimização maior com manipulação de bits, mas nada feito. Vou atualizar a resposta com essas informações.

Comment: É que no seu código não existe uma variável `q` (acho que o tamanho = `t`, período = `p`). Sobre a *performance*, *microbenchmarks* são o capeta... Talvez as conclusões sejam dependente de hardware / OS / VM. Na minha máquina (I7 @2.4, 12 Gigas, SSD, openSUSE 13.1 64 Bits, Java 8). A sua versão original roda 500k operações numa média de **89ms** (trocar a operação de módulo por uma multiplicação aumenta o tempo para ~= **120ms**). BitPeriod5 ~= **90ms** (e falha para casos como o 955); BitPeriod4 ~= **55ms** e BitPeriod3 ~= **37ms** (a implementação descrita na minha resposta).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Não estou com meu note agora, mas o resultado é bem diferente disso com um I7, 8GB, Windows 7 e Java 7. :S

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Realmente não era `q` lá, mas a ideia era ser o `p`. Eu queria o resto da divisão executada anteriormente.

Comment: `if (t % p > 0)`então né? Depois posta o seu resultado aí (ou me envia por outros meios hehehe). Abri uma lata de minhocas com os *microbenchmarks*, mas no fundo minha conclusão é que que seu algoritmo realmente executa menos instruções que o meu, se a versão *naive* está sendo mais rápida é devido ao tempo de execução das instruções mesmo (bem como predição de *branches* e coisas do gênero), se executarmos esse *microbenchmark em 30 máquinas diferentes vamos ter 30 conclusões diferentes hehehe.

Answer (score 4):

Eu particularmente acredito que a melhor(ou a mais confiável) solução é aplicar autocorrelação, é o mesmo método usado para encontrar o período em sinais, um exemplo bem prático de autocorrelação é quando você precisa encontrar a frequência(que reciprocamente é o mesmo que o período) de um determinado sinal de áudio o principio é bem parecido com o do problema proposto, a autocorrelação pode ser definida como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os passos para se chegar ao resultado esperado é:

1. Aplicar autocorrelação no vetor de bits.
2. A autocorrelação vai te retornar os pontos mais parecidos.
3. Agora com o vetor retornado pela autocorrelação encontre todos os picos deste vetor.
4. agora que você sabe todos os locais(picos), subtraia(ache a diferença) entre os picos.
5. O seu período é o resultado da primeira diferença.

Eu fiz aqui rapidamente em matlab para demonstrar o conceito, segue alguns resultados dos apresentados pelo problema:

---

```
vector = [1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1];

R = xcorr(vector);

[pks,locs]=findpeaks(R);

resultado=diff(locs);

resultado(1)

ans =

     4
```

---

```
vector = [1 0 1 0];

R = xcorr(vector);

[pks,locs]=findpeaks(R);

resultado=diff(locs);

resultado(1)

ans =

     2
```

---

```
vector =[1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1];

R = xcorr(vector);

[pks,locs]=findpeaks(R);

resultado=diff(locs);

resultado(1)

ans =

     5
```

Comment: Muito bacana Elder (e Matemática realmente permite uma programação muito sucinta para esse tipo de problema). Você teria idéia da complexidade assintótica dessa solução?

Comment: @ederwander Creio que quando diz "complexidade assintótica" o OP se refere à [ordem de complexidade do algoritmo](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexidade_de_tempo).

Comment: Ow é verdade, eu olhei rapidamente :-) confundi, pensei que ele estava perguntando por aperiodicidade, em aplicações realmente reais isso é usado em tempo-real, ou seja afinadores de guitarra, violão, piano, etc, são usados para dar a frequência de uma nota em tempo real usando este principio... claro usamos blocos fixos ou seja 1024, 2048 de tamanho :-)

Comment: Obrigado Eder (você trabalha com algo bem bacana!). E sim, estava pensando em termos de [notação Grande-O](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grande-O).

Comment: "Grande-O" é como se diz em português? Sounds funny. Podia ser Ozão :-) @AnthonyAccioly

Comment: Até a Wikipedia tem dois artigos sobre o assunto em português (Grande-O e Big-O), acho que nesses casos é melhor chamar de complexidade assintótica temporal superior (eu sei que isso é chamar vaca de animal bovino quadrupede ruminante, mas as vezes é inevitável hehehe).

Answer (score 2):

Uma semana depois do "exercício de 30 minutos" finalmente consegui chegar a uma solução usando manipulação de bits.

Esse algoritmo continua sendo de força bruta; mas conseguiu os melhores tempos conforme meus testes (em média 6 vezes mais rápido do que o algoritmo original).

### O algoritmo

> 1. Para todo candidato a período **P** entre **1** e **Q / 2**
>
>    2. Inicialize **K:** **P** bits de ordem superior em **N**.
>    3. Encontre **S:** uma cadeia de **Q** bits utilizando sucessivas repetições de **K** ("restos" devem ser considerados).
>    4. Se **S == N**, o período é **P**
> 2. Se nenhum período foi encontrado, retorna **-1**.

### Implementação

```java
public int periodo(int n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n precisa ser positivo");
    }
    int result = - 1;
    // tamanho da cadeia de bits
    final int q = 32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(n);
    // cada periodo entre p 1 e tamanho da cadeia / 2
    for (int p = 1; p <= q / 2 && result == -1; p++) {
        // primeiros p bits
        final int k = n >> q - p;
        if (n == constroiPeriodo(k, p, q)) {
            result = p;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Onde o método `constroiPeriodo` pode ser implementado da seguinte maneira:

```java
private int constroiPeriodo(int k, int p, int q) {
    int result = 0;
    // periodos inteiros
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i += p) {
        result = result << p | k;
    }
    // ultimo periodo parcial
    final int mod = q % p;
    if (mod != 0) {
        result = result >> p - mod;
    }

    return result;
}
```

---

**P.S.** Enquanto [minha adaptação](https://gist.github.com/aaccioly/fc89c6d2ab862f7a629b#file-bitperiod4-java) do [algoritmo do utluiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15570/100) não conseguiu alcançar a *performance* dessa implementação *naive*, o algoritmo dele é bem mais inteligente e deve ser preferido.