# Predecessor comum em um grafo de commits

Tags: java, algoritmo

Esbarrei novamente em um problema interessante durante uma entrevista. Infelizmente também não estou certo de que encontrei um algoritmo ótimo (ou suficientemente bom). Pensei em compartilhar para ver se alguém conhece uma solução clássica ou uma variação mais eficiente da minha implementação.

## Contexto

Uma maneira de representar um repositório de código fonte (e.g., do Git e do Mercurial) é através de um grafo de commits:

### Exemplos

1. Grafo com *commits* lineares

   ```
   C1-C2-C3-C4
   ```
2. Grafo com apenas um galho

   ```
          C5-C6
         /
    C1-C2-C3-C4
   ```
3. Grafo com um galho que foi novamente fundido (alguma tradução melhor para *merged*?) na linha principal (`C7` possui dois predecessores diretos: `C4`e `C6`)

   ```
          C5-C6
         /     \
    C1-C2-C3-C4-C7
   ```

### O problema

Implementar uma função que encontre o predecessor comum mais recente de quaisquer dois *commits* do grafo. O Grafo de *commits* é representado por um `String[]` chamado **commits** contendo todos os ids dos *commits* ordenados por data (do mais recente para o mais antigo) e um `String[][]`chamado **parentes**.

Os ids dos predecessores para um *commit* na posição `i` podem ser encontrados em `parentes[i]`. A última posição no array **parentes** é sempre `null` uma vez que representa os predecessores do *commit* raiz. Por exemplo, o grafo do exemplo 3 é representado por:

```
String[] commits = {"C7", "C6", "C5", "C4", "C3", "C2", "C1"};
String[][] parentes ={{"C6","C4"}, {"C5"}, {"C2"}, {"C3"}, {"C2"}, {"C1"}, null};
```

Se um dos *commits* é predecessor do outro, esse próprio *commit* é o predecessor comum.

#### Assinatura do método

```
String predecessorComum(String[] commits, String[][] parentes, String commit1,
        String commit2);
```

#### Exemplo:

A chamada:

```
 String predecessor = predecessorComum(commits, parentes, "C4", "C6");
```

Retorna `C2`

#### Complexidade

É possível escrever uma solução **O(n)** para esse problema.

---

### Uma primeira solução

Minha tentativa de solução começou pelos algoritmos clássicos de LCA (veja [essa questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1242/qual-a-versao-iterativa-nao-recursiva-do-algoritmo-lca-lower-common-ancestor) do [utluiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/227/utluiz)), infelizmente as solução em tempo linear se mostraram complexas e não muito fáceis de implementar utilizando lista de predecessores.

Implementei então os seguintes passos (ao meu ver, não ótimos).

1. Mapa de IDs para índices (complexidade **O(n)**) para que possa navegar eficientemente nos arrays:

   ```
   final Map<String, Integer> idParaPosicao = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
   for (int i = 0; i < commits.length; i++) {
       final String id = commitHashes[i];
       idParaPosicao .put(id, i);
   }
   ```
2. Método auxiliar recursivo para empilhar todos os predecessores de um `commit` até a raiz, incluindo ele mesmo (complexidade **O(p + n)**):

   ```
   private Stack<Integer> predecessores(Stack<Integer> visitados, int id, 
           String[][] parentes, Map<String, Integer> idParaPosicao) {
       visitados.push(id);
       final String[] parentesD = parentes[id];
       if (parentesD != null) {
           for (String parente : parentesD) {
               predecessores(visitados, idParaPosicao.get(parente), parentes, hashToIndex);
           }
       }

       return visitados;
   }
   ```
3. Montar a pilha para os dois *commits*:

   ```
   final Stack<Integer> predsC1 = predecessores(new Stack<Integer>(), indiceC1, parentes, 
           idParaPosicao);
   final Stack<Integer> predsC2 = predecessores(new Stack<Integer>(), indiceC2, parentes, 
           idParaPosicao);
   ```
4. Desempilhar os predecessores a partir da raiz enquanto eles forem iguais. O último *commit* igual é o predecessor mais recente (complexidade **O(n)**):

   ```
   int lca = -1;

   while (!predsC1.isEmpty() && !predsC2.isEmpty()) {
       final int a1 = predsC1.pop();
       final int a2 = predsC2.pop();
       if (a1 == a2) {
           lca = a1;
       } else {
           break;
       }
   }
   ```
5. Retornar o **commit**:

   ```
   return commits[lca];
   ```

### Autocrítica:

1. Enquanto penso que essa é uma solução com tempo `O(n + p)`, ela possui uma constante forte na frente, muito provavelmente algoritmos melhores já existem.
2. Funcionamento: Não possuo provas matemáticas ou mesmo confiança que esse algoritmo funcione em todos os casos (ele funcionou para o caso base e algumas outras variações).
3. Complexidade espacial: Usei um mapa e duas pilhas (além das pilhas de recursão). Tenho certeza que isso pode ser melhorado (em especial acredito que o mapa deva ser desnecessário).
4. Recursão: O método auxiliar nada mais é do que uma busca em pré-ordem recursiva. Como Java não possui otimização de cauda (reescrevi esse código em Scala e a diferença de *performance* para árvores maiores foi absurda) qualquer grafo maior resultará em *stack overflow*. Eu não consegui implementar uma solução iterativa.
5. Finalmente penso que a estrutura de dados escolhida (grafo representado por uma lista de predecessores ordenadas do *commit* mais recente para o mais antigo) deve possuir propriedades que simplifiquem o problema. Encontrei, por exemplo, vários algoritmos inteligentes para encontrar LCAs em árvores binárias de busca.

Comment: O array parentes está direito?

Comment: Está sim Jorge. Leia em reverso: Os país de `"C7"` são `{"C6","C4"}`, o pai de `"C6"`é `"C5"` e assim por diante (`"C1"` não tem pai).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creio que a sua solução não está tão subótima. A maior questão é que não é necessário montar duas pilhas de prodecessores.

Fiz uma solução alternativa só um pouquinho mais otimizada (em teoria, já que num benchmark a sua pode até ser mais rápida).

```java
public class GraphPredecessor {

    static String predecessorComum(String[] commits, String[][] parentes, String commit1,
            String commit2) {

        //validação
        if (commit1 == null || commit2 == null || parentes == null || commits == null
                || commits.length != parentes.length) {
            return null;
        }

        //caso ótimo
        if (commit1.equals(commit2)) {
            return commit1;
        }

        //mapa (commit, parents[])
        Map<String, String[]> parentMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < commits.length; i++) {
            if (parentes[i] != null) {
                parentMap .put(commits[i], parentes[i]);
            }
        }

        //adds all parents of commit1 into a Set
        Set<String> commit1Parents = new HashSet<String>();

        //iterate over parents without recursion
        LinkedList<String> q = new LinkedList<String>();
        q.push(commit1);
        commit1Parents.add(commit1);
        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            String s = q.pop();
            String[] parentsArray = parentMap.get(s);
            if (parentsArray != null) {
                for (String p : parentsArray) {
                    //for each parent, if it's commit2, then return it!
                    if (p.equals(commit2)) {
                        return p;
                    } else {
                        //otherwise just push the node for the next loop
                        q.push(p);
                        //and adds to parent list
                        commit1Parents.add(p);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //finds the first commit2 parent in commit1Parents
        q.push(commit2);
        while (!q.isEmpty()) {

            String[] parentsArray = parentMap.get(q.pop());
            if (parentsArray != null) {
                for (String p : parentsArray) {
                    if (commit1Parents.contains(p)) {
                        return p;
                    }
                    q.push(p);
                }
            }

        }

            //no luck
        return null;

    }

    public static void displayResult(String expected, String returned) {
        System.out.println("---------- TEST ----------");
        System.out.println("Exptected " + expected);
        System.out.println("Result    " + returned);
        System.out.println("Status    " + (expected.equals(returned)?"OK":"ERROR"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] commits = {"C7", "C6", "C5", "C4", "C3", "C2", "C1"};
        String[][] parentes ={{"C6","C4"}, {"C5"}, {"C2"}, {"C3"}, {"C2"}, {"C1"}, null};

        displayResult("C2", predecessorComum(commits, parentes, "C4", "C6"));
        displayResult("C2", predecessorComum(commits, parentes, "C6", "C4"));
        displayResult("C1", predecessorComum(commits, parentes, "C1", "C7"));
        displayResult("C1", predecessorComum(commits, parentes, "C7", "C1"));
        displayResult("C7", predecessorComum(commits, parentes, "C7", "C7"));
        displayResult("C6", predecessorComum(commits, parentes, "C6", "C7"));
        displayResult("C6", predecessorComum(commits, parentes, "C7", "C6"));
        displayResult("C2", predecessorComum(commits, parentes, "C2", "C7"));
        displayResult("C2", predecessorComum(commits, parentes, "C7", "C2"));
        displayResult("C2", predecessorComum(commits, parentes, "C5", "C3"));
        displayResult("C2", predecessorComum(commits, parentes, "C3", "C5"));

    }

}
```

Este algoritmo basicamente faz o seguinte:

1. Coloca todos os pais do commit1 num conjunto.
2. Vai olhando todos os pais do commit2 até encontrar o primeiro que esteja no conjunto.

Exemplificando com os dados da pergunta:

```
      C5-C6
     /     \
C1-C2-C3-C4-C7
```

Ao buscar por `C4` e `C6`, o algoritmo vai montar primeiro um conjunto com os filhos de `C4`. A saber:

```
C1, C2, C3, C4
```

Em seguida ele itera sobre os pais de `C6`:

- `C5` está no conjunto? Não, vai para o próximo.
- `C2` está no conjunto? Sim, então retorna C2.

Note que neste algoritmo nunca será necessário ler mais que `N` nós (exceto talvez na última comparação), pois ao encontrar um nó que já foi processado, o mesmo será o resultado do algoritmo.

Comment: Utluiz, sempre você ao resgate. Obrigado! Realmente bem melhor (não tive a sacada de usar um mapa de nós para os parentes), e a solução para encontrar os parentes era tão simples, não acredito que não pensei nisso hehehe.

Comment: Sobre benchmarks não vou te torrar dessa vez não, acredito em você hehehe. E perdão por postar um comentário fora do tópico mas continuo interessado nos seus números para a [questão do período](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14970/retornar-o-tamanho-do-periodo-de-uma-cadeia-de-bits) (Cheguei a rodar o  algoritmo em uma máquina Windows e realmente obtive o mesmo resultado que você, a operação de módulo é cara... Vai entender).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Vou ver se amanhã eu rodo o benchmark. ;)